# Error: Blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express

I am trying to test some api calls with a test site using express and ajax but if I separate the js script into its own file it gives the following error,

> The resource from “http://localhost:9000/userProfileFunctions.js” was
>   blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
>   (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

It works if I keep everything in the same html file but thats more like a bandaid to the problem. I have even set the express app.use header to "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" but it still doesn't work

main.html

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="userProfileFunctions.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h4>GET REQUEST USERS PROFILE</h4>
        UUID: <input id="getUserInput" type="text" name="UUID"><br>
        <input id="getUserProfile" type="button" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Comment: I ran into this problem this week (July 2021) while trying to do some basic development in Firefox instead of Chrome. Turning off Enhanced Tracking per @smore4's answer worked for that purpose.

In my case, the file being blocked was a JS file compiled from TypeScript.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a very technical answer, but I was getting this same error with testing even though the production version worked.  The error went away when I switched Off Enhanced Tracking Protection in Firefox (Developer Edition).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, it worked putting all JS files into a folder with the static files and adding the following line in the express file:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));`

I believe it's a good option to try if someone is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put that JS file in the same directory as the "importing" html file. 
I just have solved the same exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the file's location has been changed. Check the path and update your `src` tag of your script with the correct location.

```
/ChangeLocation/userProfileFunctions.js
```

example:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="/NewLocation/userProfileFunctions.js/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue, check if your file location is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this error is **commonly caused by a missing "/"** in the file path.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

will **lead to error**. But...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

**will not**. Notice the extra "/" at the start of the href.