# HTML script tag greyed out and not loading

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

The image shows what my code looks like. I have a js file I want to use but for some reason I can't load it.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script type=""src="/public/js/app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Whats that "defer" for at behind the quotation marks of src?

Comment: What does the browser console show? Getting errors?

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 this is an attribute for script tags, you should read up on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01, this is the attribute that executes the script after the page has fully loaded.

Comment: is the path to js file correct? do you see the file in network tab ?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I just checked the console and this is the message I got "The resource from “http://localhost:3000/public/js/app.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)." But im unsure what it means

Comment: @ivivjcb, try add attribute `text/javascript`. It should be like this - `<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/app.js" defer></script>`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708963/error-blocked-due-to-mime-type-text-html-mismatch-x-content-type-options check this

Answer (score 2):

I see couple potential issues here:

#1 Do you see the file in the network tab being loaded? Are you sure the path to the file is 100% correct?

#2 Add space between `type=""src="..."` or remove `type` property totally (as it's empty anyway)

#3 Do you run this on any local server? Or you open it as a static HTML file in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

You get error *"The resource from “localhost:3000/public/js/app.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."*, which indicates an empty value for the attribute `type=""`. And your webserver cannot determine the js resource type. Add the required attribute, type `text/javascript`.

Also, remove the space between the attributes - `type=""src="/public/js/app.js"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/app.js" defer></script>
```